# Getting all results from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am getting a `ResultSet` of type `ArrayList<MyClass>` and all is working well, except it's not getting the first item from the list.

It seems this part is actually taking the first option and using it, despite not actually doing anything with it:

```
if (!result.next()) {
    //throw Excepion
}
```

Then after that I run the `while (result.next()) {` and populate the `ArrayList`.

The first item in the database is just an empty `String` (well a space actually), and there are n other entries. I want the blank entry there too because this fills a `JComboBox` and need the first entry to always remain as a blank option.

But, because of checking `if (!result.next())` before the `while (result.next())`, it will only show from `item2` onwards. If I remove the `if`, it will leave the blank option in the dropdown.

Just to note, this code is using a `try...finally`.

So my issues/queries are:

**1)** Would I be best off removing the `if (!result.next())` and just putting in a `catch` for the same exception?

**2)** Is it possible to use the initial way I described, but keeping the first entry in the result?

**3)** Is there a better way to get the first entry than just having a space in the first entry in the table? (Note that if it's just literally blank, and I remove the `if`, it will show a tiny little option in the dropdown table.

Comment: If you already have `while (result.next())` then you don't need `if (!result.next())`.

Comment: So I guess they're kind of contradictory? Like checking if it's empty makes no sense if I'm then checking if it's not empty?

Answer (score 5):

Taking all items from `ResultSet` and placing them in a list goes like this:

```
List<MyObj> data = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Id, Name, ...");
    while (rs.next()) {
        int id= rs.getInt("Id");
        String name = rs.getString("Name");
        data.add(new MyObject(id, name));
    }
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}
```

You do not need to check the state of `rs`, because the check in the header of the `while` loop is sufficient.

[Oracle's reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Comment: Thanks, so a catch seems to be the way to go. One other thing; I’m filling the first row as a blank always based on an entry in the table with a space in it. Is it better to just set the first entry manually in the JComboBox, then add the array(list) or does it really matter?

Comment: @notyou Since blank entry in a combo box is really part of end-user interaction that provides a way to set blank to the combo box regardless of anything else it may contain, I would recommend setting the first entry manually. Note that `try`/`catch` above are not used in the process of actual reading, unless an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yep, I had a look at SQLException there and that’s fine that it’s not part of the reading. The while will do just fine. I implemented it earlier with the space option but it’s the weekend now so I’ll have a look at a manual blank entry instead on Monday, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check this way:

```
if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())
```

`rs.isBeforeFirst()` returns false if the resultset contains no rows.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the next() function you allways jump to the following record, you must avoid the if(!result.next()), you can use if(result != null) and then, the loop